# handlebar helper functions are not working

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require-handlebars

I am using `handlebars` in my application all the templates and their corresponding `helper`functions writing in `.html` file itself. Templates compilation happening inside my `Backbone` views so that means it's happening in `.js` file.

Before implement `require.js`,all my views instances are global that's why template compilation working fine but now I re-factor my views code into modules wise using `require.js` because of this my templates are not working while templates compilation time exceptions(`Missing helper: 'setIndex'`) are coming. This is the way I written

index.html:

```
 //loading library 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/handlebars-v1.1.2.js"></script>
 //helper function
 <script>
   Handlebars.registerHelper('setIndex', function(value){this.index = Number(value);});
 </script>
 //template
 <script id="ftpBodyInitialTpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each bizSteps}}
        {{setIndex @index}}
    {{/each}}
 </script>
```

.js file :

```
define(["handlebars"],function(Handlebars){
    //templates compilation happening here.
});
```

I don't know, why it's showing `Missing helper: 'setIndex'` can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing the first closing `</script>` tag in index.html or just the example you posted?

Comment: I added `script` tag around helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading Handlebars without RequireJS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/handlebars-v1.1.2.js"></script>
```

and then with RequireJS:

```
define(["handlebars"],function(Handlebars){
```

You did not mention a module loading error message so I'm assuming you correctly configured RequireJS to load it, and that RequireJS does load it. The problem is that you end up with **two instance of Handlebars.** The one loaded without RequireJS gets the `setIndex` helper. The one loaded with RequireJS does not. There are multiple solutions to this problem:

1. Load Handlebars without RequireJS and **avoid** loading it with RequireJS too. In this case, you'd just use the global `Handlebars` symbol that Handlebars exports. You don't list `handlebars` in the modules that your modules require.
2. Load Handlebars with RequireJS and **avoid** loading it without RequireJS. You'd have to remove the `script` tag that loads Handlebars and the helper would have to become an AMD module.
3. Load Handlebars without RequireJS and **fake** loading Handlebars in RequireJS. You could keep your code as it is now. You'd configure RequireJS like this:

   paths: {
       handlebars: "path/to/handlebars-fake.js"
   }

And the `handlebars-fake.js` file would be:

```
define(function () {
    return Handlebars;
});
```

So RequireJS would end up with the same instance of Handlebars as the one loaded with `script`.